# UCanAccess: unexpected token from spaces

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, ucanaccess

I'm trying to insert numbers/text into a table, but when the program tries to insert the text, I get the error
`net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.2 unexpected token: EX1 required: )`

Here is my relevant code:

```
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
   "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + dbPath  
   +   ";newdatabaseversion=V2010"
   )) {
   DatabaseMetaData dmd = conn.getMetaData();
     try (ResultSet rs = dmd.getTables(null, null, tableName, new String[] { "TABLE" })) {
          try (Statement s = conn.createStatement()) {
                ResultSet resultSet;
                String tableName = "Database";
                s.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE " + tableName +" ( [SUBJID] 
                INTEGER, [PARAMCD] TEXT, [PARAM] TEXT, [AVAL] DOUBLE)");
                String s1="Text Ex1";
                String s2="Text Ex2";
                int a=3;
                double b=2;
                resultSet = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName);
                s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO " + tableName
                    + " ( SUBJID, PARAMCD, PARAM, AVAL)"
                    + " VALUES ( "+ a+", " + s1 + ", " + s2 +" , " + b +" )");
```

It looks to me that the error is caused when a blank space appears. I've tried changing s1 to "TextEx1" and s2 to "TextEx2", which gives me the error of `net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.2 user lacks privilege or object not found: TEXTEX1`.

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can offer.

Comment: Calling table `Database` is not best idea. Plus with `Text Ex1` you need proper quoting or parameter  binding (it will be safer).

Comment: What do you mean by proper quoting?

Comment: Just print `"INSERT INTO " + tableName
                    + " ( SUBJID, PARAMCD, PARAM, AVAL)"
                    + " VALUES ( "+ a+", " + s1 + ", " + s2 +" , " + b +" )"`

Comment: Isn't that what I did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do something like this:

```java
String sql = "INSERT INTO [" + tableName + "] (SUBJID, PARAMCD, PARAM, AVAL) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setInt(1, a);
ps.setString(2, s1);
ps.setString(3, s2);
ps.setDouble(4, b);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thanks Gord, this worked perfectly. What would I do if I wanted to update it instead of insert? I tried replacing the "INSERT INTO" with "UPDATE" , but that gave me an error of "net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.2 unexpected token: ( required: SET".

Comment: The UPDATE syntax is a bit different, e.g., `UPDATE [Database] SET PARAMCD=?, PARAM=? WHERE SUBJID=?`

Comment: I used String sql = `"UPDATE [" + tableName + "] SET SUBJID=?, PARAMCD=?, PARAM=? WHERE AVAL=?";`, which worked for the most part- however, I encountered problems when my "AVAL" value was found in multiple rows, as it updated each of them when I only wanted to update the most recent one. I tried changing it to `String sql = "UPDATE [" + tableName + "] SET SUBJID=?, PARAMCD=?, PARAM=?, AVAL=? WHERE PARAMCD=? AND SUBJID=?";`, but received an error of `net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.2 Parameter not set`. Is there any way I can add multiple paramaters or something?

Comment: This is getting off-track for comments to a specific answer. You should ask a new question.